# Reactive elasticsearch repository does not save items passed from Flux stream

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to persist some data in my reactive repository.

```
public class ArticleRepositoryMultiIndexImpl implements ArticleRepositoryMultiIndex<Article> {
  private final ReactiveElasticsearchOperations operations;

  @Override
  public Flux<Article> saveAll1(Iterable<Article> entities) {
    var indexOps = operations.indexOps(indexName());
    indexOps.createSettings(Article.class);
    return operations.saveAll(entities, indexName());
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// b is a Flux<Article>, and is not empty 
articleReactiveRepository.saveAll1(b.toIterable());
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you consume the Flux that `articleReactiveRepository.saveAll1()` is returning?

Comment: nothing happens until you subscribe... `articleReactiveRepository.saveAll1(b.toIterable());` is just a declaration, you need to return out to the calling client, so that the calling client can subscribe to it.

Comment: doing `var saved = articleReactiveRepository.saveAll1(b.toIterable());
    saved.subscribe(
        article -> {
          System.out.println(article.getArticle().getTitle());
        });` does not help